# Android - Checking WiFi name periodically until a condition

Tags: android, android-intent, service, alarmmanager

I am trying to build a Reminder App.
In this app, user will select a WiFi name which is saved on the phone. And when the user connects to that WiFi, Phone is going to vibrate. And after phone vibrates, service is going to die.

I have tried to write a Service to check the WiFi name in every 1 minute.  When I close the app, it runs again but not as I expected.

Service Implementation:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "com.wificheckalways";
public static String wifiToCheck = MainActivity.wifiName;

public AlarmService(){

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand called");

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String ssid = "";
            ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
                    ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
                }
            }

            while(!wifiToCheck.equals(ssid)){
                Log.i(TAG, "Goes to SLEEP");
                synchronized (this){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                        Log.i(TAG, "WAKE UP");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
                        ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Compare " + wifiToCheck + " with " + ssid);
                    }
                }

            }

            if(wifiToCheck.equals(ssid)) {
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(2000); // 2000 miliseconds = 2 seconds
            }
        }
    };

    Thread alarmThread = new Thread(runnable);
    alarmThread.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY; //Restart service if it got destroyed
}

public void onDestroy(){
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroyCommand called");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Where I start the service in MainActivity.java:

```
public void SetAlarm(View view) {
    if (!wifiName.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set for: " + wifiName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please choose a WiFi name!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

wifiName is the choosen Wifi.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I would use broadcast receiver inside service that will receive message when WiFi connection changes. From that message I would extract information about connection and check if WiFi's SSID is equal to saved SSID. If it is, phone would vibrate. That way you wouldn't have to use threads.

Comment: So, service will run to check if the WiFi connection has changed? If yes, then I will get the current SSID and compare with the chosen SSID. Am I right? But I still can't understand how to use Broadcast Receiver in it :/

Comment: [Context-registered broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#context-registered_receivers), [broadcast receiver for connection change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47202596/4778343). When creating service (`onCreate`) register for connection change (and of course unregister in `onDestroy`). Your code for checking if user is connected to particular SSID would go inside broadcast receiver's method `onReceive`. In this case, you would stop service after vibration.

Comment: One last question, what happens if the WiFi that the user connected, if not the chosen WiFi?

Comment: Nothing. You're still going to have `if (wifiToCheck.equals(ssid))`. If they're not equal, your service will still wait for user to connect to particular (chosen) WiFi. If they're equal, phone will vibrate and you will stop your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, your service could look like this:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    public AlarmService() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        String ssid = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
                        if (ssid.equals(<<ENTERED_SSID>>)) {
                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(2000);
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The only part that's "missing" is entered SSID.

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to stop the service in activty `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` methods like `stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmService.class));`

Comment: From MainActivity? But I don't know when the user is going to connect to the chosen WiFi. So when should I call stopService?